# How do i alert the user if it is not numeric value for percentage?

Tags: javascript, html

I alert the user when the value is out of bounds:

```
   if (document.myForm.outputPercentage.value <= 0 || document.myForm.outputPercentage.value >= 100)
    {
        alert( "Percentage output must be between 1 - 100" )
        document.myForm.deviceId.focus() ;
        return false;
   }
```

But I want to first check if value is a valid number, how do I do that?

Comment: Whats wrong with your current code?

Comment: Why not use `<input type="number" min="0" max="100">`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use isNaN function, it will return true if parameter is not a number and false if parameter is a number

```
if(isNaN(document.myForm.outputPercentage.value )){
alert('not a valid input');
 }
```

Comment: OP wants to know whether the value is in a specific interval, not whether it is a number.

Comment: He seems to be asking for both

Comment: How come you know Mr.  Turing85  what OP wants. Without thinking anything you downvoted my answer. Have some patience and let the asker reply.

Comment: In any case, this answer only does half of the work and is incomplete

Comment: OP is incredibly bad in asking questions. I think he wants to ask for a number validation (which Vivek provides) and shows his range validation code for unkown reasons.

Comment: Thanks a ton @PieterDeBie. But dnt know what to say about  Turing85 who without thinking too much just downvotes.

Comment: Maybe you could improve your answer by including the isNaN check inside his if statement. Everybody happy :)